# Backbone this confusion

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this

I have the following code:

```
var GoalPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Bind to the goal panel DOM element
    el: $("#sidebar-goals"),    

    // Initialize the collection
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = Goals;
        this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);
    },

    // Create a new goal when a user presses enter in the enter goal input
    createOnEnter: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
        this.addItem();
        //Goals.create(this.newAttributes());           
    },

    // Add the goal item to the goal list
    addItem: function() {
        var goal = new Goal();
        goal.set(this.newAttributes());
        var goalsElem = this.el;
        this.collection.add(goal);
        $(this.el).children("#enter-goal").val('');
    },

    // Append DOM element to the parent el
    appendItem: function(item) {
        var goalView = new GoalView({
            model: item,
        });
        $(this.elem).append(goalView.render().el);
    }

});
```

My problem is inside of the `appendItem` function. When I use `this` inside of the `appendItem` function, I believe that it thinks that the `this` refers to the `this.collection` rather than the `GoalPanelView`. How would I get the `this` to refer to the `GoalPanelView` rather than the `collection`? I tried to pass another variable into the `appendItem` function which held the contents of `this.elem`, but it didn't seem to work.

One thing that worked was when I moved the `appendItem` function into the `collection` and changed the initialization to bind to `this.collection.bind('add', appendItem);` but I do not want to put the `view` stuff into the `collection` logic.

Comment: An alternative is putting `_.bindAll(this)` in your initialize function. That ensures that any function called within the object will be applied with the value of `this` bound properly to the object itself. Useful if you're writing lots of callbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a scope when binding an event handler, like so:

```
this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem, this);
```

The scope sets the value of `this` inside the handler. In you case, the current object.

**Edit:** [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) has a great explaination why `this.appendItem` does not actually carry the scope of the function itself, it's just a function pointer, not a method pointer. One of the quirks of Javascript..

**Edit 2** [Backbone Reference - Events / on](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on)

Answer (score 2):

Just to update (as of Backbone 0.9.2), the proper way to do this is:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on("add", this.appendItem, this);
    ...
}
```

Depending on your use case, you may also want to consider:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.appendItem);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, it would be better to use "this.listenTo", so unbinding the event will automatically happen when calling remove. This way you will prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use underscore's `_.bindAll` function in your `initialize` method:

```
initialize: function() {
   _.bindAll(this);
   this.collection = Goals;
   this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);
}
```

Now any call to any method on `GoalPanelView` (e.g. `appendItem`) will be scoped such that references to `this` refer to the `GoalPanelView` instance.

You can also pass in a list of method names as strings if you don't want to scope all the methods of `GoalPanelView`

See here: http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll